Sarkovskiis theorem and the Cantor set
Can we prove the following as such (with relevance with the Sarkovskiis theorem)?

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and that $A_0 , A_1 ,\dots, A_n $ are
closed intervals and $f(A_i) \supset A_{i+1}$ for $i = 0, 1, \dots , n- 1$, i.e. $f(A_0)\supset f(A_1)\supset f(A_2)$. Prove that there exists a point $x \in A_0$ such that $f^i(x) \in A_i$ for $i = 1, \dots , n$.

Interpretation:
Let the  minimal case be that we need to prove that if  $x\in A_0$, then $f^1(x)\in A_1$ for $f$ on $A=[A_0\cap A_1\cap\dots \cap A_n]$, where $f$ is continuous and where $f(A_0)\supset f(A_1)\supset f(A_2)\supset\dots \supset f(A_n)$
Proof
Let $f$ be continuous, and let $x\ne y$, then $\exists$ $\epsilon>0\ni |x-y|=\epsilon$, and $\exists \ \delta>0\ni |f(x)-f(y)|=\delta$. \
Now, let $f(x)=x^3+x$. Let $f^1(x)=x^3+(1+\epsilon) x$. Let the sets $A_n$ be the Cantor set, hence we have
$$ \mathcal{C}:=  \lim_{n\to \infty}=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}=\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty}  m\geq 0.$$
Consider, $$ C_{0}:=[0,1] $$ and
$$ C_{n}:={\frac {C_{n-1}}{3}}\cup \left({\frac {2}{3}}+{\frac {C_{n-1}}{3}}\right)={\frac {1}{3}}{\bigl (}C_{n-1}\cup \left(2+C_{n-1}\right){\bigr )}$$
Let  $y\in C_0=[0,1]$, but $y\not\in C_1=[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac23,1]$,  then clearly, since $f^1(y)=y^3+(1+\epsilon)y$, and $\epsilon>0$, then $$\underset{f^1(y)}{sup} \in[C_0].$$ Then since $C_1\subset C_0$ $$\underset{f^1(y)}{sup} \not\in[C_1],$$ hence $f^i(x)\in C_i$ for $f$ on $C=[C_{1} \cap C_2\cap\dots \cap C_n]$ where $f(C_0)\supset f(C_1)\supset f(C_2),\dots\supset f(C_n)$.
